# Puzzled with Closure Parameter in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

sorry for the novice question, but i really do not understand

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.characters.count == 0{
        searchActive = false
        tableView.reloadData()
        return
    }

    searchActive = true
    filteredTableData = tableData.filter({( spaTown: String) -> Bool in
        let rangeTupple = (spaTown.startIndex, spaTown.endIndex)
        let spaRange = Range(uncheckedBounds: rangeTupple)
        let stringMatch = spaTown.range(of: searchText, options: String.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive, range: spaRange, locale: NSLocale.autoupdatingCurrent)
        return stringMatch != nil
    })

    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

The part i do not understand is the

```
filteredTableData = tableData.filter({( spaTown: String) -> Bool in
```

I don't understand how the function knows that spaTown string is the string that i wish to search through? Isn't it some arbitrary parameter name?

It puzzles me a lot..

Comment: You are correct, it is an arbitrary name. The `filter` method takes a closure, and applies to each element in the array, creating a new array containing only those elements which the closure returned `true`. `spaTown` is the arbitrary name given to the element of the array; if you have an array of `spaTown`s then it makes sense to name each element `spaTown`.

Comment: @jjatie Yes.. But how does the filter function or its closure knows which array is this "spaTown" pointing to?

Comment: It's being called on `tableData` so it iterates through each element in `tableData`

Comment: @jjatie Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The system knows the type of the closure it's expecting as the argument to `filter` - it's expecting `(Element)->Bool` where `Element` is the type of the array elements.

When your code says `{( spaTown: String) -> Bool in` you're defining the closure that you're passing to it.  You can use any name you like for the String variable - you chose *spaTown*. This is exactly like the parameters of a function: `func f(spaTown:String)->Bool { ... }`  As long as the *types* match, the compiler is happy.

Comment: Thanks for replying.. I guess the main confusing part for me was not knowing which element of tableData is passed into the closure... But jus like jjatie has pointed out, it is the individual element of the tableData that is passed into the closure. Solved.. Nonetheless, thanks